# Proof Verification: Largest and Smallest Topologies (Kelley 1.A)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Problem:
>
> a) The intersection of any collection of topologies on $X$ is a topology on $X$ (Kelley 1.A)

Attempt:

- Let $\mathcal K$ be a collection of topologies on $X$. For every $\tau \in \mathcal K$, we know $X \in \mathcal \tau$, so $X \in \bigcap \mathcal K$.
- Let $A, B \in \bigcap \mathcal K$. Then, for every $\tau \in \mathcal K$,
  $A \cap B \in \tau$, so $A \cap B \in \bigcap \mathcal K$.
- Let $\gamma$ be a subfamily of $\bigcap \mathcal K$. Then, for every
  $\tau \in \mathcal K$, $\gamma$ is a subfamily of $\tau$, so
  $\bigcup \gamma \in \tau$. It follows that $\bigcup \gamma \in \bigcap \mathcal K$. In particular, when $\gamma$ is empty, we see $\emptyset \in \bigcap \mathcal K$.

> b) The union of two topologies on $X$ may not be a topology on $X$.

Attempt:

Let
$$\begin{align}(X,\tau) &= \left(\{0,1,2\},\{\emptyset,01,012\}\right) \\ 
(X,\gamma) &= \left(\{0,1,2\},\{\emptyset,12,012\}\right)
\end{align}$$
We see that
$$
(X, \tau \cup \gamma) = \left(\{0,1,2\},\{\emptyset, 01, 12, 012\}\right)
$$
is not a topology on $X$ because $01 \cap 12 = 1 \not \in \tau \cup \gamma$.

Comment: Yep, looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proofs seem valid. There's little else to say really.

At the end I would use set notation like, say, $\{0,1,2\}$ instead of $012$.

Comment: Perhaps at the end there are some notational issues to fix?